# .htaccess - adding redirect with wildcards

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm noticing a lot of 404s on my site that look like:

`/category1/category2/slug-name/subdirectory`

`category1`, `category2` and `slug-name` all vary,  but subdirectory should never be there (it is always the same subdirectory, though.)

I just want to create a simple redirect, I'm just not super familiar with .htaccess syntax.

Essentially the redirect should be:

```
https://www.example.com/no/matter/what/is/here/subdirectory
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/no/matter/what/is/here/
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/subdirectory$ $1/ [QSA,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RedirectMatch directive

Try this in htaccess file that is in The root folder

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/subdirectory/?$ /$1
```